# Issue related to setup of Symfony 3.4

Tags: symfony-3.4

I have installed PHP 5.6.40, and have also run command

```
symfony check:requirements
```

in accordance with https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/requirements.html
Its output is shown below.

> /usr/local/bin/symfony: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token
> `newline' /usr/local/bin/symfony: line 1:` '

Comment: And what's your question about this? PHP 5.6.40 is out of support since more than three years, and there's absolutely no need to run Symfony 3.4 (which is unsupported since Nov 2021) on such an old PHP version

Comment: @NicoHaase, I mean I installed PHP ver. 7 to create Symfony 6 project, and it was not working, because of some semantical error in DocParser.php for \@Route.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. If you really installed Symfony 6 on PHP 7, why does your question mention Symfony 5.4 and PHP 5.6.40?